# Fill array with new items (android-section-list)

Tags: android, arrays, listview, arraylist, addition

I have this example from the ["android-section-list"](https://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/)Project:

```
SectionListItem[] exampleArray = {
            new SectionListItem("Test 1 - A", "A"), 
            new SectionListItem("Test 2 - A", "A"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 3 - A", "A"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 4 - A", "A"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 5 - A", "A"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 6 - B", "B"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 7 - B", "B"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 8 - B", "B"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 9 - Long", "Long section"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 10 - Long", "Long section"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 11 - Long", "Long section"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 12 - Long", "Long section"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 13 - Long", "Long section"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 14 - A again", "A"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 15 - A again", "A"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 16 - A again", "A"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 17 - B again", "B"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 18 - B again", "B"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 19 - B again", "B"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 20 - B again", "B"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 21 - B again", "B"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 22 - B again", "B"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 23 - C", "C"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 24 - C", "C"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 25 - C", "C"),
            new SectionListItem("Test 26 - C", "C"),
    };
```

But I must fill the array items programmatically from a database.
The following ist only to make clear what I thought the result should be.
I know that the syntax is totally wrong, but I think you now what I mean to what I want to go to:

```
Cursor mCursor = mDbHelper.getChecklistAllByTitle();
    // looping through all entries and adding to list
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        SectionListItem[] exampleArray = {
        do {
            new SectionListItem(mCursor.getString(1),mCursor.getString(2));
            }while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        +};
    }
    mCursor.close();
```

As I allrady said, the code is naturally wrong...I know...but have no solution :-(
How can I get it to fill the array correct with iterating the DB entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've no doubt noticed, a native array isn't dynamic and you don't know how many entries you are going to need until you've been over all the data from the database. So start with an ArrayList instead which does grow as you need it to:

```
ArrayList<SectionListItem> my_list = new ArrayList<SectionListItem>();
```

Then iterate over the cursor, adding to the ArrayList as you go:

```
while (mCursor.moveToNext())
{
    my_list.add(new SectionListItem(mCursor.getString(1),mCursor.getString(2));
}
cursor.close();
```

You can then convert the ArrayList to a native array using the toArray method:

```
SectionListItem[] exampleArray = my_list.toArray(new SectionListItem[my_list.size()];
```

Comment: or `SectionListItem[] array = new SectionListItem[mCursor.getCount()];` then `array[mCursor.getPosition()] = new SectionListItem(mCursor.getString(1),mCursor.getString(2));`